# Another xml python extract

Tags: python, xml

i'm lost i want to extract a value from url xml file in python i saw tha there a lot of library but unable to have some success.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root LoadTime="1360991134" DataVersion="991138826" UserData_DataVersion="991134040"   
TimeStamp="1361131034" ZWaveStatus="1" LocalTime="2013-02-17 14:57:14 D">
<Device_Num_82 status="-1">
<states>
<state id="72" service="urn:upnp-org:serviceId:XBMCState1" variable="Port" value="80">   
</state>
<state id="73" service="urn:upnp-org:serviceId:XBMCState1" variable="PingInterval"    
value="180"></state>
<state id="74" service="urn:upnp-org:serviceId:XBMCState1" variable="PingStatus"  
value="up"></state>
<state id="75" service="urn:upnp-org:serviceId:XBMCState1" variable="IdleTime" 
value="program"></state>
<state id="76" service="urn:upnp-org:serviceId:XBMCState1" variable="PlayerStatus"   
value="Video_end"></state>
<state id="77" service="urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:HaDevice1" variable="CommFailure" 
value="1"></state>
<state id="78" service="urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:HaDevice1" variable="LastUpdate" 
value="0"></state>
<state id="79" service="urn:micasaverde-com:serviceId:HaDevice1" variable="Configured" 
value="0"></state>
</states>
<Jobs></Jobs>
<tooltip display="0"></tooltip>
</Device_Num_82>
</root>
```

i want the value of id=75 (program)

Thanks

Here the code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib.request

VERA = 'http://192.168.2.19:3480/data_request?id=status&output_format=xml&DeviceNum=82'

xml = urllib.request.urlopen(VERA).read()
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
print (tree.find('.//state[@id="75"]').attrib['service'])
# urn:upnp-org:serviceId:XBMCState1
```

Here the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Michael/Desktop/test.py", line 8, in <module>
print (tree.find('.//state[@id="75"]').attrib['service'])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Then no `state` node with an id of "75" exists...

Comment: I know why now, i check with the browser and everytime i refrech the id change. is there a way to check for the variable IdleTime instead

Comment: Got it now thanks so much i chande the id to variable and the IdleTime . Thanks so much

Comment: It working on a stanalone script but when try it in xbmc, it does not work xbmc seems to use an older version of elementtree. Is there a way to extract it with the version that come with xbmc

Comment: No idea - you'd have to look into what interpreter version `xbmc` uses, but that's a bit out of scope for here

Answer (score 0):

Where `xml` is a string of your data, then using `lxml`, you can do:

```python
import lxml.etree as ET

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
print tree.xpath('//state[@id="75"]/@service')
# ['urn:upnp-org:serviceId:XBMCState1']
```

Alternatively, you can do the following using the builtin `xml` library:

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
print tree.find('.//state[@id="75"]').attrib['service']
# urn:upnp-org:serviceId:XBMCState1
```

Comment: The python is for xbmc addon so is there a standard method without installing other library or is there a way to include the library with the python script?

Comment: @user2052746 made an edit using the builtin `xml` library with Python